# Not able to update the cell with new data as (cell!=nil)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [cell addButtons:buttonsArray];
    }

    [cell renderCell:[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

On **viewDidAppear** buttonArray changed, so  I want to update my cells with new buttonArray. I am using `[tableView reloadData]` but as `(cell != nil)` I am not able to update

Comment: So where is the problem? If cell is != nil, then the cell has obviously previously passed the inner if-block and therefore has the buttons already added to it - just use them.

Comment: Please update your question as it is  clear

Comment: @luk2302 I updated my question. Can you please check now. Thanks

Comment: maybe but [cell addButtons:buttonsArray]; outside of the if statement?

Comment: @JonasSchafft It's not efficient if there are lot of cells and if I add them outside the if statement then buttons will be added one above other while scrolling the tableView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion is you can add the buttons if the cell is nil and change the data of the buttons outside the if condition

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [cell addButtons:buttonsArray]; // add the buttons
}
[cell updateButtonData:dataArray]; // update the data on the button
[cell renderCell:[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
return cell;
}
```